# F# Change element in list and return full new list

Tags: f#

I have a list of type `(string * (int * int)) list`. I want to be able to search through the list, finding the right element by it's `string` identifier, do a calculation on one of the `ints`, and then return the full, modified list.

Example:

Given a list

`let st = [("a1",(100,10)); ("a2",(50,20)); ("a3",(25,40))]`

I'm trying to make a function which gets one of the elements and subtracts number from one of the `ints` in the tuple.

```
get ("a2",10) st 
//Expected result: st' = [("a1",(100,10)); ("a2",(40,20)); ("a3",(25,40))]
```

I feel I'm almost there, but am a little stuck with the following function:

```
let rec get (a,k) st =
    match st with
    | (a',(n',p'))::rest when a'=a && k<=n' -> (n'-k,p')::rest
    | (a',(n',p'))::rest                    -> (n',p')::get (a,k) rest
    | _                                     -> failwith "Illegal input"
```

This returns `[("a2",(40,20)); ("a3",(25,40))]` and is thus missing the first `a1` element. Any hints?

Comment: why you expect it to return from "a1"?

Comment: I know that my own function does not return from "a1", but I would like to end with a function that returns the entire, modified list, whereas the current one returns from the modified element, and then the rest of the list.

Comment: I mean the output you see perfectly matches the implementation. If you want the whole list, you need to pass head,tail to `get` recursively, with head growing and tail shrinking, if you want to keep recursive implementation, of course.

Comment: or, rather, on the second case for `match st`, you can return `(a', (n', p'))::(get (a, k) rest)`, but this is going to break tail recursion.

Comment: I just changed the second match case and it seems to get the work done. I would have to think more to get a tail recursive version.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lists are immutable, so if you want to "change one element" you are really creating a new list with one element transformed. The easiest way to do a transformation like this is to use `List.map` function. I would write something like:

```
let updateElement key f st = 
  st |> List.map (fun (k, v) -> if k = key then k, f v else k, v)
```

`updateElement` is a helper that takes a key, update function and an input. It returns list where the element with the given key has been transformed using the given function. For example, to increment the first number associated with `a2`, you can write:

```
let st = [("a1",(100,10)); ("a2",(50,20)); ("a3",(25,40))]

st |> updateElement "a2" (fun (a, b) -> a + 10, b)
```

Comment: I was looking for an idiomatic way to update elements by their indexes, then i got an idea of  turning my List into a Map with keys as items' indexes. That way i don't have to define my own update function, and i can pipe ``` Map.add ``` functions already.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a function which would update an element in a list based on the element's data. I couldn't find one in F#5, so wrote one using Tomas' solution:

```
let updateAt (elemFindFunc: 'a -> bool) (newElem: 'a) (source: 'a list) : 'a list =
source
|> List.map
    (fun elem ->
        let foundElem = elemFindFunc elem
        if foundElem then newElem else elem)
```

`elemFindFunc` is the function which consumes an element and returns `true` if this is the element we want to replace. If this function returns true for multiple elements, then those will be replaced by `newElem`. Also, if `elemFindFunc` evaluates to `false` for all elements, the list will be unaltered.

`newElem` is the new value you want to replace with. `newElem` could be replaced by a function like `valueFunc: 'a -> 'a` if you want to process the element before inserting it.