# How to change item in list at specific index in F#? (Property 'Item' cannot be set)

Tags: list, indexing, f#

I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game, where a user inputs a 2 digit number. The first digit is the position and the second is 1 or 0 for X and O. I've been searching for how to change an item in a list but can only find how to append or concatenate items.

```
open System

let mutable game = [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9 ]
let mutable won = false

while not won do
    printfn "%A" game
    let pos = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())
    // game.[pos.[0]] <- pos.[1] doesn't work

Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Comment: The List module has many functions that you can use to solve this. But that would probably be inefficient. I think you should simply turn `game` into an array. Then you can do what you try in that outcommented line.

Comment: Thanks, Bent. I'll change it to array for now and check out some of the functions for lists soon.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857249/f-change-element-in-list-and-return-full-new-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you mark a variable as mutable (as in the case of `game`), it means that you can mutate the variable itself by assigning a new value to it (i.e. `game <- [...]`) but it does not make the data structure itself mutable. In your case, the list is still immutable.

A way to do this that keeps the structure similar to what you have is to produce a new list where the value at the entered index is changed and all other values are as before. You can do this using `List.mapi` (I also changed how the parsing of the string is done):

```
let pos, value = int (input.[0]), int (input.[1])
game <- game |> List.mapi (fun i v -> if i = pos then value else v)
```

An alternative would be to use a mutable array - that way, you could mutate the element at a given index, but if you are learning F#, then it's a good idea to stick to the functional data structures.

Answer (score -2):

You need some sorting algorithm, as *insertion* sort. This way you can keep track what pairs from matrix is matched.

Comment: I didn't understand that, could you show me an example? I just need to be able to change a specific number in the game list, I know how to check if the game is won I can do that after.

Comment: Was check and find Array.sortWith can help. Just make sortFunction that suit you best. I was thinking triplets matching from pre-defined matrices with bool matcher.